# Getting a model in the controller

Tags: model, controller

Is there any difference in these two inside a frontend controller?
Performance or memory wise? In the end both are doing `createModel`, right?
Thanks!

```
$model = $this->getModel('Object', 'Site');
```

vs

```
$model = $app->bootComponent('com_mycomp')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Object', 'Site', ['ignore_request' => true]);
```

Comment: Are the controller and model within the same component?